# Find a checkbox for only certain repeats in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I will try to paraphrase my question and try to code an example but is in asp.net and C#.

I have a repeater that inside in a bunch of checkboxes. The table is laid out similar to this...

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%#Eval("question")%></td>
        <td><a href="edit.aspx?id=<%#Eval('id')%>">Edit</a></td>
        <td>Applies to the following</td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_A" runat="server" Text="Model A" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_B" runat="server" Text="Model B" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_C" runat="server" Text="Model C" /></td>
    </tr>
<ItemTemplate>
```

When it databinds it receives the question, id, and a list of models to be Checked the first time... so

Question 1..(ID)10... A C ...

But how do i get it to check chkModel_A and chkModel_C because they are in the repeater and I can have multiple questions in this table so when it does Question 2 it won't get A C and gets whatever question 2 is.  Currently, it only checks the last or maybe it's the first databinded question.  Thanks for any help!

I forgot to add the databinding...

```
protected void rptQs_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
        RepeaterItem ri = e.Item;
        foreach(string model in modelsSplit) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) ri.FindControl("chkModel_" + model);
            if (cb != null) {
                cb.Checked = true;
             }
         }
}
```

Here is the result after a databind.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is question 1</td>
        <td><a href="edit.aspx?id=1">Edit</a></td>
        <td>Applies to the following</td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_A" runat="server" Text="Model A" Checked="true" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_B" runat="server" Text="Model B" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_C" runat="server" Text="Model C" Checked="true" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is question 2</td>
        <td><a href="edit.aspx?id=2">Edit</a></td>
        <td>Applies to the following</td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_A" runat="server" Text="Model A" Checked="true" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_B" runat="server" Text="Model B" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_C" runat="server" Text="Model C" Checked="true" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This is question 3</td>
        <td><a href="edit.aspx?id=3">Edit</a></td>
        <td>Applies to the following</td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_A" runat="server" Text="Model A" Checked="true" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_B" runat="server" Text="Model B" /></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_C" runat="server" Text="Model C" Checked="true" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get each row in the table to have the correct checkboxes checked.  Instead all of them are checked the same way. I can't get Question 2 or 3 to show properly. Hope that helps explaining.

Comment: `how do i get it to check chkModel_A and chkModel_C because they are in the repeater ....` ***Please do not write run-on sentences; it is hard to read. Could you rephrase where you get stuck?***

Comment: i want it to select chkModel_A and chkModel_C. They are in a repeater. It only looks at the last databinded line and all the other repeated checkboxes get checked for chkModel_A and chkModel_C.  So I end up with 3 questions all with A and C selected which isn't right.

Comment: `It only looks at the last databinded line and all the other repeated checkboxes get checked for chkModel_A and chkModel_C.` ***What does it mean? Could you post the screen shot?***

Comment: Win, I updated the question with the html code for the table that is produced. Hopefully that makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that you're unable to access and thus, manipulate the checkbox elements in your code-behind. Right?

To overcome this, you are going to have to find the control using `FindControl`. Something like the following:

Your aspx:

```
// Set the OnItemDataBound attribute of your repeater 
<asp:Repeater ID="yourRepeaterId" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="SomeFunctionName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("question")%></td>
            <td><a href="edit.aspx?id=<%#Eval('id')%>">Edit</a></td>
            <td>Applies to the following</td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_A" runat="server" Text="Model A" /></td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_B" runat="server" Text="Model B" /></td>
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkModel_C" runat="server" Text="Model C" /></td>
        </tr>
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in your code behind file:

```
void SomeFunctionName(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Checkbox chkbox_A = (Checkbox)e.Item.FindControl("chkModel_A");
    Checkbox chkbox_B = (Checkbox)e.Item.FindControl("chkModel_B");
    Checkbox chkbox_C = (Checkbox)e.Item.FindControl("chkModel_C");
    // Use or manipulate chkbox_A, chkbox_B, chkbox_C as per your requirements...
}
```

The above technique can be used to refer to anything inside a repeater, even another repeater (in the case of nested repeaters). I hope this helps...

Comment: all the chkModel_A's get checked! The last repeated row (tr) determines which checkboxes get checked but its always that rows checks.  And all the other rows (tr) get checked the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to cast **e.Item.DataItem** to appropriate object inside **ItemDataBound** event.

[image]

### ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("question")%></td>
                <td><a href="edit.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>">Edit</a></td>
                <td>Applies to the following</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkModel_A" runat="server" Text="Model A" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkModel_B" runat="server" Text="Model B" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkModel_C" runat="server" Text="Model C" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Code Behind

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test { Id = 1, Question = "One", A = true, B = false, C = true},
            new Test { Id = 2, Question = "Two", A = false, B = true, C = true},
            new Test { Id = 3, Question = "Three", A = false, B = true, C = true},
        };
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        var test = e.Item.DataItem as Test;

        var a = item.FindControl("chkModel_A") as CheckBox;
        a.Checked = test.A;

        var b = item.FindControl("chkModel_B") as CheckBox;
        b.Checked = test.B;

        var c = item.FindControl("chkModel_C") as CheckBox;
        c.Checked = test.C;
    }
}
```

Comment: Win, the datasource is listed more like I said in the question. It shows..."Question 1" "10" "A,C"

Comment: Do you want to allow a user to select only one option at a time - like radio buttons? For example, either A, B or C.

Comment: No. They can select A,B,C or B,C or A,B or A,C and that is just with Models A thru C. If an additional model D gets added, it would get more complicated.

Comment: I'm confused. What part doesn't work in my solution? Could you post the screenshot of what you want - explain with text and arrows in the screenshot?